# springmvc handler more url with internal

Tags: java

I have this web application

```
@RestController
public class SomeController {

    @GetMapping("/info")
    public JsonResult<XXX> info() {
        XXX xxx = // this urls's business
        return JsonResult.success("info msg", xxx);
    }

    @GetMapping("/type")
    public JsonResult<List<yyy>> type() {
        List<yyy> yyyList = // this url's business
        return JsonResult.success("type msg", yyyList);
    }
}
```

And now, I want a this url

```
@GetMapping("/multi")
public JsonResult url(List<String> urls) {
    // if urls=info,type
    Map<String, Object> result = Maps.newHashMap();
    for (String url : urls) {
        // just GET method, other ignore
        JsonResult jsonResult = handlerToUrl(url); // 1 to handler SC#info() 2 to SC#type()
        if (jsonResult != null && jsonResult.getData() != null) {
            result.put(url, jsonResult.getData());
        }
    }
    return JsonResult.success("more info", result);
}
```

This problem occurs because when used in an app (iOS, Android), the content of a page consists of multiple URLs.

I'm trying to do this

```
static final Map<String, List<String>> URL_MAP = Maps.newHashMap();
static {
    URL_MAP.put("detail", Arrays.asList("SC#info", "SC#type"));

    // etc.
}

@Autowired
private RequestMappingHandlerMapping mapping;

@GetMapping("/url")
public JsonResult url(String type) {
    if (isBlank(type)) {
        return JsonResult.fail("need some input");
    }

    List<String> urls = URL_MAP.get(type);
    if (isBlank(urls)) {
        return JsonResult.fail("no this page");
    }

    Map<String, Object> result = Maps.newHashMap();
    for (String url : urls) {
        // just first, other ignore
        HandlerMethod handlerMethod = first(mapping.getHandlerMethodsForMappingName(url));
        if (handlerMethod != null) {
            Object urlResult = null;
            try {
                // XXX
                urlResult = handlerMethod.getMethod().invoke(handlerMethod);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                // ignore
            }
            if (urlResult != null && urlResult instanceof JsonResult) {
                Object data = ((JsonResult) urlResult).getData();
                if (data != null) {
                    result.put(url.substring(url.indexOf("#") + 1), data);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return JsonResult.success("multi info", result);
}
```

but in // XXX line, I have this Execption

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at xxx.UrlController.url(UrlController.java:40)
```

Looks like it Not allowed to call the method in the internal call in spring mvc, this will change the life of the url request.

Does some body has some good suggestions?